# White screen when opening a page in the Form.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application, which I can open URIs in a Windows.Form.WebBrowser. Everything work well, but when I want to change the URI I get something strange happens to the opened page:

If the Windows.Form.WebBrowser is created and the navigate method is called, I get a white screen splash( for 1 second) before the URI is shown.

does anyone know what this white screen is?

cheers,
ES

Comment: its probably the default generic space while it downloads the new file.

Comment: Is there any method to access it and change the color of the generic space?